# How to check if an export operation is complete in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, gcloud

I am trying to create a datapipeline starting with Firestore export to a GCS path and once it is completed start data transport and import to BigQuery. The Firestore export from Google's documentation submits the process/job or operation as it is called and then exits without actually waiting for the export process to complete. There is an option to check with gcloud utility. Is there a better way to check the status of completion and then trigger the subsequent processes?

Answer (score 1):

As per [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import#managing_export_and_import_operations) after you start an export or import operation, Cloud Firestore assigns the operation a unique id. You can reveal this id with ‘[gcloud firestore operations list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/operations/list)’ command and using this id you can run ‘[gcloud firestore operations describe [OPERATION_NAME]](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/operations/describe)’ to get information about the operation. This request returns ‘workEstimated’ and ‘workCompleted’ metrics.

***workEstimated:*** shows the estimated total number of bytes and documents an operation will process.

***workCompleted:*** shows the number of bytes and documents processed so far. After the operation completes, the value shows the total number of bytes and documents that were actually processed, which might be larger than the value of workEstimated.

*Divide workCompleted by workEstimated for a rough progress estimate. This estimate might be inaccurate, because it depends on delayed statistics collection.*

Additionally I would like to recommend you to take a look at this [Scheduling data exports Guide](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export), to get more insights how to build more efficient export-import architecture using Google Cloud tools such as Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Yes, my question is about what happens after following the instructions. Ideally I would expect some kind of a callback after the process is completed without writing a process that continuously issuing gcloud firestore operations command that checks the status of the process. That's wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to poll with the command line gcloud firestore operation describe until the status is 'Successful and then perform my import. Until there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You have posted a comment and not an answer. You already received the correct answer by @Jaroslav.

Comment: @JohnHanley , Jaroslav's answer was just repeating the what I mentioned in the question. I know we can use  the command line utility. But there is no way to do that programmatically. That has not been answered. Just copying text from online documentation doesn't constitute an nswer.